# Get rid of CORS in CouchDB?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, cors, pouchdb

I have a problem when I try to replicate a database from PouchDB to CouchDB. [image]

Here is the code I use for database replication

```
       var db = new PouchDB('todos');
       var remoteCouch = 'http://localhost:5984/db/';

function sync() {

     var opts = {live: true};
      db.replicate.to(remoteCouch, opts);
 };
```

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:** there is now an  [add-cors-to-couchdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/add-cors-to-couchdb) script that makes this dead-simple:

```
npm install -g add-cors-to-couchdb && add-cors-to-couchdb
```

As documented in the PouchDB [getting started guide](http://pouchdb.com/getting-started.html), to enable CORS you need to do:

`$ export HOST=http://username:password@myname.iriscouch.com
$ curl -X PUT $HOST/_config/httpd/enable_cors -d '"true"'
$ curl -X PUT $HOST/_config/cors/origins -d '"*"'
$ curl -X PUT $HOST/_config/cors/credentials -d '"true"'
$ curl -X PUT $HOST/_config/cors/methods -d '"GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE"'
$ curl -X PUT $HOST/_config/cors/headers -d \
  '"accept, authorization, content-type, origin"'`

We also document this in the [common errors](http://pouchdb.com/errors.html), but apparently its Googlability is still not high enough.  :)

Comment: Notice for all installing couchdb on debian/ubuntu via package manager. As of today (10-Oct-2014) the version you will get is 1.2 and it does NOT support CORS options. If you want to use them you have to install never version from sources. It took me a bit to realise why my CORS settings did not work, and the reason was I've installed it via apt-get install couchdb and it was version 1.2.